# I am trying to search for a string using the search() function in Vimscript

Tags: search, vim, pattern-matching

My code is as follows.

```
let l:foundtag = search("<.>")
echo l:foundtag
```

This code will return the line number where the tag was found.

Using the code example above, I would like it return the string "< p >" (or whatever other tag it finds). Is there any way to get the actual string that has been found by the search instead of just the number of the line where it was found using Vimscript?

Comment: `echo getline(search("<.>"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo getline(search("<.>"))
```

As stated in the comment is a possibility if you only want the first found tag.
Else you could use:

```
split(execute("g/<.>/p"), "\n")
```

But be aware, that both these functions will return the whole line. It seems like you want only the label. Then you have to wrap it in a `matchstr` command.

```
echo matchstr(getline(search("<.>")), "<.>")
```

Also note that this will only find tags with a single character. If you want to find longer tags like `<div>` you must adapt your regex to something like `"<\\w*>"`